# adding characters to base of filename with powershell

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\WPDOCS-aa\0000-wpdocs 2015" -Filter "wpd" -Recurse | rename-item -NewName {$_.name-replace '.wpd', -2015.wpd'}

PS C:\WPDOCS-aa\0000-wpdocs 2015> Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\WPDOCS-aa\0000-wpdocs 2015" -Filter "wpd" -Recurse | rename-item -NewName {$_.name-replace '.wpd', -2015.wpd'}
```

I have tried the above and it just hangs.
I tried this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\WPDOCS-aa\0000-wpdocs 2015" -Filter "wpd" -Recurse | rename-item -NewName {"$($_.BaseName) -2015.wpd"}
```

and it seemed to complete (Powershell v5 with W10 Pro) but there were no file changes. 
I would like to thank someone here for their initial help.

Comment: I suggest you to split your code in blocks and ensure that Get-ChildItem does the trick, then that the filter does its work and only then add rename-item

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your approach.

1) The -Filter isn't getting the files you want because you are looking for files literally called "wpd". You need to use a wildcard if you're only providing part of the file name. Since it sounds like you're looking for files specifically with the .wpd extension, it would be like so:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\WPDOCS-aa\0000-wpdocs 2015" -Filter "*.wpd" -Recurse
```

2) To have access to the `$_` pipeline variable you need first to wrap the Rename-Item in a Foreach-Object cmdlet.

```
Foreach-Object {Rename-Item -Path $_.Fullname -NewName "$($_.BaseName) -2015.wpd"}
```

One more small note is that you can make your cmdlet more reusable if you don't hard-code the .wpd extension. I would do the -NewName parameter more like this:

```
-NewName ($_.BaseName + " -2015" + $_.Extension)
```

That way if you want to reuse this with some other file type, all you have to change is the filter section.

So the whole thing all put together would be:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\WPDOCS-aa\0000-wpdocs 2015" -Filter "*.wpd" -Recurse | Foreach-Object {Rename-Item -Path $_.Fullname -NewName ($_.BaseName + " -2015" + $_.Extension)}
```

Comment: Thank you for your corrections. I will try them out this weekend

Comment: Thank you so much, Christopher.  I thought I would give it a quick try now and it worked beautifully!

Comment: I am just a novice with Powershell. I am continuing on my renaming project. I used the following to copy all wordperfect files beginning with “a” to a single folder.  (There are over 40,000 files in 20 plus main folders with several subfolders (also with subfolders, alphabetized) 

The following command worked but the way I have this set up, it is also copying the folders and subfolders.  I am trying to copy just the files to a new folder e.g “A”

cd C:\WPDOCS-SKY

Copy-Item -Path c:\WPDOCS-SKY -Filter "a*.wpd" -Recurse -Destination c:\wpdocs-alph\A

Answer (score 0):

Backup your files first, then try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\WPDOCS-aa\0000-wpdocs 2015" -Filter "*.wpd" -Recurse | % { rename-item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.BaseName)-2015.wpd" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a little simpler to just do the following:

```
dir *.wpd | rename-item -NewName {$_.BaseName + "-2015" + $_.Extension}
```

Since `dir` is a shorter alias for `Get-ChildItem` and the filter can be passed directly as a parameter with the current directory the assumed path. It's also a closer analog to the original DOS for those of us old folks here.